# How to add room to DHTMLX scheduler

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dhtmlx-scheduler

How to add Rooms Horizontally against time in DHMLX Scheduler in my ASP.Net MVC application

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it using [Unit view](http://scheduler-net.com/docs/unitsview.html).

To initialize the Units view and add it to the scheduler, use the code below:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    var sched = new DHXScheduler(this);
    ...
    var unit = new UnitsView("unit", "room_id");//initializes the view
    sched.Views.Add(unit);//adds the view to the scheduler

    return View(sched);
}
```

where
unit - the name of the view.
The constructor requires the 'name' cause the view can exist in the scheduler in several instances.
room_id - the name of a property used as the id of units.

More detailed guide you can find on the [DHTMLX Scheduler .NET](http://scheduler-net.com/docs/unitsview.html#initialization) website

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. Could you please add one or two example as well so others can easily understand what you mean?

Comment: Thank you sir that's good and work successfully but sir i  only want the unit view(rooms) as a  default view and i want to remove all other Day Week and Month(only Unit view show on my calendar)